# Object.defineProperty data binding scope

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, defineproperty

I have been playing with the javascript `Object.defineProperty` to create data binding. I did get it to work. My question is has to do with something else.

I have a for html query to look for elements with the attribute 'data-bind' and loop through them in a for-loop. From withing the for-loop I call a function to bind them through the setter property:

```
var cbinder = function(obj, elem, prop) {
      Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, {
        set: function(val) {
          elem.innerHTML = val;
        }
      });
    };
```

// called from

```
 var elem = document.querySelectorAll("[data-bind]"); 
 for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
            var prop = elem[i].getAttribute("data-bind");
            cbinder(obj, elem[i], prop);
        }
```

```js
 var obj = {};
 var cbinder = function(obj, elem, prop) {

   Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, {
     set: function(val) {
       elem.innerHTML = val;
     }
   });
 };

 window.onload = function() {
   var elem = document.querySelectorAll("[data-bind]");

   for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
     var prop = elem[i].getAttribute("data-bind");
     cbinder(obj, elem[i], prop);
   }


   var btn = document.querySelector("#chnbtn");
   btn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
     obj.fname = "John";
     obj.lname = "Doe";

   }, false);


 };
```

```html
<p>
  <span data-bind="fname">my name</span>  <span data-bind="lname">my name</span>
</p>
<p>
  <button id="chnbtn">Change Values</button>
</p>
```

Since I call this function within the for-loop I figured I might as well integrate it there, ***but here is where my issue rises. It does not work correctly and only assigns the last value when setting the object.*** Why is the first example working fine and the second fails, while they are in my opinion similar calls. Can someone clench my curiosity?

```
   var elem = document.querySelectorAll("[data-bind]");
   for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        var prop = elem[i].getAttribute("data-bind");
        var el = elem[i]
        Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, {
            set: function (val) {
                el.innerHTML = val;
            }
        });
    }
```

```js
    var obj = {};
    window.onload = function() {
      var elem = document.querySelectorAll("[data-bind]");

      for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        var prop = elem[i].getAttribute("data-bind");
        var el = elem[i]
        Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, {
          set: function(val) {
            el.innerHTML = val;
          }
        });
      }


      var btn = document.querySelector("#chnbtn");
      btn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        obj.fname = "John";
        obj.lname = "Doe";

      }, false);


    };
```

```html
<p>
  <span data-bind="fname">my name</span>  <span data-bind="lname">my name</span>

</p>
<p>
  <button id="chnbtn">Change Values</button>
</p>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - Thanks for pointing that one out to me. I would have not thought to link that to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setter function you're assigning to your property has an *enduring reference* to the `el` variable, not a *copy* of it as of when the function was created. So when the function is called, it's trying to use the last value `el` had in the loop.

Your original code, putting that off in a function, was the way to go.

Comment: Thanks ... Your answer definitely was the first big pointer for me. After reading some more into the link above I now understand what is going on here. First time I run into this tricky trap ;-)